# printing two things together in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have two ints (or anything else for that matter) and I wish to print them to the terminal together, ie. without spaces, newlines or anything else in between. I only have access to python 2.7 and I can't appear to be able to do that. So I have a and b. a=0, b=1, my desired output is:

> > 01

how?

Answer (score 0):

use '+' operator to concatenate the variables

```
a,b = 0,1 
print str(a)+str(b)
```

output

```
01
```

In case of number you need to force them to string using `str`
if they are already string no need to us `str`
Example:

```
a='hello'
b=' world'
print a+b
```

output:

```
hello world
```